# jquery prevAll() on same class

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a star rating system. When i mouse over the 5th star, want to add the class 'active' to all the previous stars, some goes for if i mouse over any other element with the class `.star-span`.

The elements:

```
<label class="star-span" for="rate-one"></label>
<label class="star-span" for="rate-two"></label>
<label class="star-span" for="rate-three"></label>
<label class="star-span" for="rate-four"></label>
<label class="star-span" for="rate-five"></label>
```

my Jquery code so far:

```
$('.star-span').mouseenter(function()
{
    $('.star-span').prevAll('.star-span').addClass('active');
})    
$('.star-span').mouseleave(function()
{
    $('.star-span').prevAll('.star-span').removeClass('active');
});
```

Now when i mouse over any of the elements. the first 4 spans will get the class. Not the prevous elements of the element i hovered over.

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `this` like below. `this` is the instance of current element for which mouseenter or mouseleave event happened

```
$('.star-span').mouseenter(function()
{
    $(this).prevAll('.star-span').addClass('active');
})    
$('.star-span').mouseleave(function()
{
    $(this).prevAll('.star-span').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler you need to use this to refer the current star

```
$('.star-span').mouseenter(function()
{
    $(this).prevAll('.star-span').addClass('active');
})    
$(this).mouseleave(function()
{
    $('.star-span').prevAll('.star-span').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This event also works fine as per your requirements.

```
$('.star-span').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).prevAll('.star-span').addClass('active');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).prevAll('.star-span').removeClass('active');
});
```